# How to combine/minify Css files?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Pub build copies my /css files to /build/web/css, that's great. In our .Net post-build step we call AjaxMin to combine/minify all css into *.min.css files. In DartWorld is this accomplished via a custom build.dart with Transformer? Is there an example app/code-snipet demonstrating proper Dart way to accomplish this?  If not, any suggestions helpful too!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done by transformers expecially if it needs to modify source files.
There is already a transformer available for SASS.

Some documentation is already available about how to build custom transformers:

- https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html
- https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/index.html

For some tasks something like [hop](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/hop) may be a good fit too.

Comment: Thanks, definitely need to explore Transformers. Until then, I created build.dart with several regexp to do the job during fullBuild.

Comment: @osstekz, could you share your code? It would help others.